# Shell script to compare two tables and perform operations on their columns

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have two tables like the following:

Table 1

```
TABLE_NAME                            COUNT
------------------------------ ------------
AIN_EDP_SCRIPT                           33
AMA_CALLTYPE_LOOKUP                      24
APPLICATION_INFO                          0
ARS_PROFILE                               0
AUTHCODE                                  0
AUTHCODE_GROUP                            0
AUTHCODE_INFO                             0
AUTHO_RIZATION                            1
AUTO_RECALL_PROFILE                       0
AUTO_RECALL_PROFILE_DATA                  0
BG_REGISTERED_USER                        0
BILLING_INFO_PROFILE                     18
```

Table 2

```
TABLE_NAME                            COUNT
------------------------------ ------------
AIN_EDP_SCRIPT                           23
AMA_CALLTYPE_LOOKUP                      24
APPLICATION_INFO                          0
ARS_PROFILE                               0
AUTHCODE                                  23
AUTHCODE_GROUP                            0
AUTHCODE_INFO                             0
AUTHO_RIZATION                            1
AUTO_RECALL_PROFILE                       0
AUTO_RECALL_PROFILE_DATA                  34
BG_REGISTERED_USER                        0
BILLING_INFO_PROFILE                     18
```

I want to subtract 2nd column of Table 2 from the 2nd column of Table 1 and output results in the following Table 3, like:

Table 3

```
TABLE_NAME (This remain same)        COUNT(Table2-Table1)
------------------------------ ------------
AIN_EDP_SCRIPT                           33
AMA_CALLTYPE_LOOKUP                      24
APPLICATION_INFO                          0
ARS_PROFILE                               0
AUTHCODE                                  0
AUTHCODE_GROUP                            0
AUTHCODE_INFO                             0
AUTHO_RIZATION                            1
AUTO_RECALL_PROFILE                       0
AUTO_RECALL_PROFILE_DATA                  0
BG_REGISTERED_USER                        0
BILLING_INFO_PROFILE                     18
```

Can you please let me know how I can do it in bash?

Comment: That is almost entirely unreadable. If you are looking for people to help you with your issue please would help them by editing your question and using the formatting features.

Comment: @Shah Hussain; if you post sample data, please post them accurately. In the second column of the third table you should put the correct values (i.e. the differences) of the expected output. Please edit your question and correct that.

Comment: @Janis unfortunately the OP appears neither to update questions in the light of new information nor mark answers as accepted. Look to the other Stacks for evidence, but I would gladly be shown to be wrong in this regard.

Comment: @roaima i am really sorry, i didnt noticed the output to be distorted. Thanks to dhag, its corrected now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to create the table with the value differences:

```
paste table1 table2 | awk 'NR<=2 { print $1, $2 ; next } { print $1, $4-$2 }'
```

(Note: If you want them formatted like in the original files use `printf` instead of `print` with appropriate format specifiers.)

Edit: Here is a variant of the above command (using a conditional operator) that uses `printf`:

```
paste table1 table2 | awk '{ printf "%-30s %12s\n", $1, NR<=2 ? $2 : $4-$2 }'
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Can you kindly also add some tip on printf, if i want to get output in the same original tables format.

Comment: The `printf` command expects a format string like `"%-20s"` to put a string (indicated by the s) left-aligned (the minus) in a field of width 20. I'll add some code to my answer. The `printf` has many options; you may want to inspect a manual for that. Note that most `printf` support the same basic set of format specifiers; so for the command do `man printf` or inspect the `awk` or C library documentation).